# Plupload chunk size renaming file to Blob

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, plupload

I'm using Plupload in order to download file. The configuration we have is the folowing :

```
$("#uploadData").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        url: serviceurl,

        // Maximum file size
        max_file_size: '50mb',

        chunk_size: '1mb',

        max_file_count: 50,

        unique_names: true,

        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            quality: 90,
            crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
        },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [
            { title: "Documents Excel", extensions: "xlsx" }
        ],

        init: {

            FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                up.start();
            },

            UploadComplete: function (up, files) {
                if (up.total.uploaded == up.files.length) {
                    $(".plupload_buttons").css("display", "inline");
                    $(".plupload_upload_status").css("display", "inline");
                    up.init();
                }
            }
        },
```

The problem i have is when i upload a file that is bigger than 1MB, i don't receive the right name, instead i receive Blob for name.
For exemple, the name of my file is "Test.xlsx" and the size is 2MB, i will receive, on the server side, "blob" for name and not Test.

Limitation, i'm not allowed to change the chuck size limitation on the client.
How can i get the right name.

Thank for your help.

code used to receive the data on the server side :

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadData(int? chunk, string name)
        {
            var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];

            if (Session["upDataFiles"] == null)
            {
                Session["upDataFiles"] = new List<FileUploadViewModel>();
            }

            Session["upDataFiles"] = UpdateTempDataUpload(fileUpload.FileName, name, (List<FileUploadViewModel>)Session["upDataFiles"]);

            UploadFile(chunk, name);
            return Content("chunk uploaded", "text/plain");
        }

private void UploadFile(int? fileChunk, string fileName)
        {
            var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];
            var uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            var fullPath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName);
            fileChunk = fileChunk ?? 0;
            using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName), fileChunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
                fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
```

When i check the name in the request.File object, it's blob and not the actual name.

Comment: How do you retrieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was described in detail on [GitHub](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/398). It might be a little confusing, but from what I understand:

- $_FILES[ 'name' ] will obligatorily be 'blob' if you use chunks.
- They seem to claim that $_REQUEST[ 'name' ] should have the real name, but the users seem to disagree.
- As a workaround it is proposed to send the filename along in another form field or url parameter (using for example the `BeforeUpload` event to set that information). You can set `multipart_params` and store your information on the file object that you added before or look at a field in your html to get information at this point.

Comment: This is correct, I had to workaround the same problem a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the answer by nus a bit:

I used the `BeforeUpload` event in Javascript as described in the [GitHub post](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/398) and then had to make a change server-side.

Previously, to get the file name I'd used:

```
var file = Request.Files[f];
var fileName = file.FileName
```

However, this had been where '`blob`' was being returned. Instead, I made a change so while I still used `Request.Files[f]` for the file details, I derived the file name like so:

```
var file = Request.Files[f];
var fileName = Request.Params["name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BeforeUpload event under init as below:

```
init : {
    BeforeUpload: function(up, file) {
        log('[BeforeUpload]', 'File: ', file);
    }
}
```

Also add log function:

```
function log() {
var str = "";

plupload.each(arguments, function(arg) {
    var row = "";

    if (typeof(arg) != "string") {
        plupload.each(arg, function(value, key) {
            // Convert items in File objects to human readable form
            if (arg instanceof plupload.File) {
                // Convert status to human readable
                switch (value) {
                    case plupload.QUEUED:
                        value = 'QUEUED';
                        break;

                    case plupload.UPLOADING:
                        value = 'UPLOADING';
                        break;

                    case plupload.FAILED:
                        value = 'FAILED';
                        break;

                    case plupload.DONE:
                        value = 'DONE';
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (typeof(value) != "function") {
                row += (row ? ', ' : '') + key + '=' + value;
            }
        });

        str += row + " ";
    } else {
        str += arg + " ";
    }
});

var log = $('#log');
log.append(str + "\n");
// log.scrollTop(log[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

And then you can get Filename in `$_POST['name']` or `$_REQUEST['name']`.
Also you can set `unique_names` as `false`.
You can also find help [here](https://www.plupload.com/examples/events)